# Can't Bake Metal From High to Low Poly

Tags: texture-baking, baking

so I'm trying to bake this high resolution belt buckle with this antique metallic procedural texture, but it's not looking correct after it finishes baking as a normal map. I googled this and to my understanding, by default, Blender has no option to bake a metal material. Is that correct? Do I need an add-on to do this or is there a way to get the nodes setup to bake this look from my high poly model to the low poly one?[image]

Comment: You can plug the metallic mask into the Base Color and bake as diffuse.

Comment: I tried that, but what was easiest for me was  baking two different images of the buckle: a roughness image baked with the roughness bake setting and a normal map image baked with the normal map setting. I connected the roughness image node to the roughness of the principled bsdf, connected the normal map image to the normal map node, then to the input of the principled bsdf. I then adjusted the strength setting on the normal map node. Thanks for the help though.